# Boundary condition for np.linalg.solve?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following problem:

I have a system of 9 linear coupled equations, with 9 variables I want to solve for. I wrote it in Matrixform, so I can solve it like

A = 9x9 array (matrix)

b = 9x1 array (vector)

x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)

Now my problem is, that I need a boundary condition that three of the elements of the solution should be one, x_00 + x_44 + x_88 = 1.

How do I implement that?

** (For people who know physics, basically I am solving for the steady state solution of a density matrix. And there is a reason why I solve it semi-analytically :) )

** I get a solution already now, but it is different from the solution I get in wolfram mathematica, where I can implement the boundary condition.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you're taking 9 linear equations in 9 variables, and then imposing another constraint, so you know have 10 constraints on 9 variables: There is a potential for the system to be overdetermined here, which is why there isn't an obvious way to do this. Can you clarify if you know that the linear equations are definitely linearly (in)dependent? If not, you might need to use numpy's [least-squares approximation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html).

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer! What you said was indeed true, and I realized I was able to completely remove one of the equations and add the boundary condition as an additional one. So at the end I had 9 again... and then it worked! 
(I am used to work in mathematica, where this would not be an issue, so i didn't think that this would be a problem.... now I learned something! :) )

Comment: Great, I'm glad you were able to solve it :) You can probably mark this question as closed in that case, or add an answer for yourself detailing how you solved the problem.